# What does Australia do to get kids into winter sports at an early age

Tags: olympics, skiing, snowboarding, ice-skating, bobsleigh

Australia is a mostly tropical/sub-tropical country. There is a small mountain range in the southeast of the country which receives snowfall for a couple of winter months. We can say that overall, the environment in Australia is far from the typical countries which dominate winter Olympics. Yet, Australians have been consistently winning medals since the '90s. What system (funding, infrastructure, marketing, support and rewards for athletes, etc.) has it put in place to achieve this success?

Comment: Useful overview: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australia_at_the_Winter_Olympics

Comment: Already read that article.